# Filtrar un arreglo de objetos con un arreglo de ids con javascript

Tags: javascript, array, json

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un arreglo de objetos, los cuales tienen una propiedad id y tengo un arreglo de ids que quiero usarlo para filtrar el arreglo de objetos, es decir del arreglo de objetos solo quiero mantener los que coincidan con alguno de los ids del arreglo

```html
const enterprise = [
    {   id:105,
        empresa:'Sony',
    },
    {
        id:115,
        empresa:'Microsoft',
    },
    {
        id:120,
        empresa:'Fromsoftware',
    },
    {
        id:125,
        empresa:'Samsung',
    }
]
const id = [125, 105]

//resultado esperado
const newEnterprise = [
    {   id:105,
        empresa:'Sony',
    },
    {
        id:125,
        empresa:'Samsung',
    }
]
```

Intenté usar el método filter pero no sé como recorrer id por id para hacer la comparación.
De antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

no encontré forma(probablemente la haya) de hacerlo con métodos nativos de js pero lo hice de forma manual

```js
const result = []

enterprise.forEach(element =>{
    ids.forEach(id=>{
        if (element.id===id) {
            result.push(element)
        }
    })
})

console.log(result);
```